# Randomly assign treatment within differently sized groups + dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have individuals within four groups.

```
df <- data.frame(group=c(rep(1, 90),
                     rep(2, 110),
                     rep(3, 105),
                     rep(4, 95)),
             id=1:400)
```

I'd like to randomly assign each individual within each group to one of five treatments. I can do that for each group seperately, but I was wondering how that would be done in a `dplyr` routine?

In the end, the `df` should look sth like this:

```
id   group   treat
 1   1       5
 2   1       4
 3   1       4
 4   1       3
 5   1       3
```

Comment: Something like this ? `df %>%  mutate(treat = sample(5, n(), replace = TRUE))`

Answer (score 2):

We can use `sample` with `replace = TRUE`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(treat = sample(5, n(), replace = TRUE))

#    group  id treat
#1       1   1     3
#2       1   2     4
#3       1   3     5
#4       1   4     4
#5       1   5     5
#6       1   6     1
#7       1   7     5
#....
```

Obviously, you can do it directly as well without any packages

```
df$treat <- sample(5, nrow(df), replace = TRUE)
```

Also a thing to note here is `sample(5)` works same as `sample(1:5)` as it is a single digit number it is automatically expanded to `1:5` within `sample`.

Comment: This will work fine, though it is not a assignment per groups. Use `df %>% group_by(group) %>% mutate(treat = sample(5, n(), replace = TRUE))` to perform function per groups (but again you should see no differences, @Ronak Shah way does it perfectly).

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, treat := sample(5, .N, replace = TRUE)][]
```